# How to remove unnecessary EFI entries from GRUB?

Tags: boot, grub2

[image: This is how my GRUB menu entry looks like]

How I can get rid of these unwanted GRUB menu entries. My Ubuntu and Windows is getting loaded properly but these unnecessary entries I don't need it. Thanks in advance.
This is how the grub.cfg(/boot/grub/grub.cfg) looks like in my case:

```
# BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="5"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt7'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=30
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=30
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-49-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-49-generic-advanced-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-49-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-49-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-49-generic-recovery-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-49-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-48-generic-advanced-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-48-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-48-generic-recovery-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-48-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-46-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-46-generic-advanced-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-46-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-46-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-46-generic-recovery-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-46-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-44-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-44-generic-advanced-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-44-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-44-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-44-generic-recovery-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-44-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-advanced-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-recovery-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###

menuentry "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root E467-1A3B
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root E467-1A3B
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
}

menuentry "EFI/HP/SystemRecovery/bootmgfw.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root E467-1A3B
chainloader (${root})/EFI/HP/SystemRecovery/bootmgfw.efi
}
### END /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-E467-1A3B' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  E467-1A3B
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root E467-1A3B
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt7'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-49-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-49-generic-advanced-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-49-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-49-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-49-generic-recovery-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-49-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-48-generic-advanced-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-48-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-48-generic-recovery-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-48-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-46-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-46-generic-advanced-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-46-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-46-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-46-generic-recovery-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-46-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-44-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-44-generic-advanced-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-44-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-44-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-44-generic-recovery-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-44-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-advanced-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-recovery-0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0307c8a7-964b-4f91-9eb0-31dddf1eee73 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###

menuentry "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root E467-1A3B
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root E467-1A3B
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
}


### END /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-E467-1A3B' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  E467-1A3B
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root E467-1A3B
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/backup25_custom ###

menuentry "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root E467-1A3B
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
### END /etc/grub.d/backup25_custom ###
```

Comment: Couldn't follow the link. It gave a 404.  You can use the key combination `ctrl + G` or select the 'img' option in the editor directly above the text field. That way, the image is tied to the post.

Comment: Please check your link was broken, so removed, enter your valid link again

Comment: posted the image now.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275315 - following on that thread also for the same problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally i am able to resolve this issue...went thru each and every file under /etc/grub.d/ directory and got rid of the entries not needed and then ran 'sudo update-grub'. I went into 25_custom and wiped all the entries into which were not needed(to boot into at the time of startup - like all the unnecessary EFI entries).

```
sudo gedit  /etc/grub.d/25_custom
sudo update-grub
```

Please make sure to make a backup  of the files you are editing. Make sure that you are not storing any of the backup files starting with 25_custom...if you store it with 25_custom_today'sdate etc....EFI boot loader will still read the entries from that....For folks who have HP Laptop - this will definitely work for you.Thanks for all your help.

**Update**
Faced this issue again with my Dell XPS Desktop. This time I need to do the same for custom_40 and custom_41. Please refer to anything under `/etc/grub.d` to find out the issues specific to your machine.

**Another alternative to do this:**
Use grub-customizer - graphical user interface

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
grub-customizer
```

[image: egrub-customizer on my machine]
Now highlight the entry and remove it
Save the changes once done.

With next reboot - you can check those unwanted entries are gone.
[image] and good part about grub-customizer is that in the right side - it has the removed items - one can revert back some or all of them if you have deleted something by mistake.
Also don't forget to [purge the old kernels](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels) so that you can save on disk space also.

Answer (score 3):

To remove EFI entries from UEFI efibootmgr is used.

You can list entries by

```
sudo efibootmgr
```

And remove entries by

```
sudo efibootmgr -Bb <entry_number>
```

[Efibootmgr manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/efibootmgr.8.html)

Comment: not helpful:ashu@ashu-700-430qe:~$ sudo efibootmgr
[sudo] password for ashu: 
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0001,0002,000A,0007,0008,000B,000C,0000
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0001* USB Floppy/CD
Boot0002* USB Hard Drive
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0007* USB Floppy/CD
Boot0008* Hard Drive
Boot000A* ATAPI CD-ROM Drive
Boot000B* CD/DVD Drive 
Boot000C* Realtek PXE B03 D00
ashu@ashu-700-430qe:~$ 
ashu@ashu-700-430qe:~$

Answer (score 2):

To clean your Grub entry you have to decide which menuentry to remove, First let's edit the custom file script in  the /etc/grub.d dir contain same content of your `grub.cfg`.

```
gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Copy all contents and go to the file  /etc/grub.d/40_custom

```
sudo gedit  /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

Append the copied content to the lines founded in the 40_custom.

Now In this custom file just remove all menuentries that you don't want to appear in your Grub menu. Take sure to remove the node of the menuentry which is enclosed by { }

Now when you  finish Save the 40_custom file and exit from gedit

Then run the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This command will create a new boot menu in the file /boot/grub/grub.cfg that contains the custom menu items that we have specified.

You can check, ahead of rebooting, just to be sure, by using the command: gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg. This will open the file in read-only mode.

If the file is as you expect then go ahead and reboot else check where you have an error.

you can read some articles for more info such as [this](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html) and [this](https://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/grub2-revisited/).

Comment: This is a wrong way for UEFI.

Comment: It looks like grub menu, not UEFI. And did you run Boot-Repair? Boot-Repair adds all the efi files it finds into 25_custom. So you can backup 25_custom and edit at will. Then run the `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Thanks oldfred I will try that...please specify the steps in more details.

Comment: @Maythux
No that doesn't work...it will in fact make the situation even worse.

Comment: Read links in the last line they have full details, perfect to learn from

Comment: Sorry @Maythux not able to follow what you mentioned.