# Windows doesn't boot after restoring grub

Tags: grub2, boot-repair, windows-10

I've been trying to solve the problem on my own using this forum and others but I can't fix it.
I had ubuntu and windows 10 installed and both worked fine. Then, a week ago or so, windows was updated and grub disappeared. I finally had the time yesterday to try and restore grub and I managed to do it using Boot-repair on a live cd, but now the problem is the opposite: I get the grub screen but when I select the windows option (any of the 3) I only get a black screen. 
Here is the boot-repair info for the grub restoring:

paste.ubuntu.com/14581993

The grub screen shows these options:

1. Ubuntu
2. Advanced options for ubuntu
3. Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi
4. Windows Boot UEFI loader
5. EFI/Ubuntu/MokManager.efi
6. Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdb2)
7. System Setup

From what I've gathered reading some posts, i may have to edit the 6th entry? But I've no idea of what to change so help is much apreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does anybody else have any idea of what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the #6 option i.e. Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdb2) to get into Windows. Once you are in Ubuntu you can try this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
grub-customizer
```

and move the Windows entry up so that your laptop/desktop goes directly into Windows.

I will suggest to remove these three entries
Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi
Windows Boot UEFI loader
EFI/Ubuntu/MokManager.efi

You can refer to this thread
[remove un-necessary EFI entries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643839/how-to-remove-unnecessary-efi-entries-from-grub)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. The thing is, I do select that option, but Windows doesn't start, I just get a blank screen.