# How To Clean Up Ubuntu 16.04 Boot Menu Alongside Windows 10

Tags: grub2, 16.04

Total newbie on Linux as of two days ago.  Running Ubuntu 16.04.  Just got a new HP Pavilion with Windows 10 64bit

I know enough to safely set up a dual boot system without breaking anything but the GRUB boot menu is a little frustrating with so many options.  I really only want the option of booting from either of the OS installed but am met with a list of options.

If all this is necessary I guess I'll leave it but I'd really only like to have the two operating systems as boot options.  So do I really need this big list of boot options or can it be reduced some how to only be the two OS options?

Boot menu:

[image]

Comment: Look at: `How to remove unnecessary EFI entries from GRUB?`  http://askubuntu.com/questions/643839/how-to-remove-unnecessary-efi-entries-from-grub