# Beep sound when turning on laptop

Tags: laptop

I get a beep sound when I turn on my laptop. I have Ubuntu os , Whats the problem ?
I even get many option when starting os like Ubuntu , advanced option etc.

Comment: Please list out these options in your post.

Comment: Please list out these options in your post.

Answer (score 2):

You need to consult your laptop's manual to find out what those beep sounds mean?

Regarding the various options in grub menu like ubuntu and advanced options etc...that's very standard. Please refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643839/how-to-remove-unnecessary-efi-entries-from-grub) for more details.

Mine`(/etc/default/grub)` looks like this

```
ashu@ashu-700-430qe:/etc/grub.d$ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"



  [1]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2
```

If you are having a lot of un-necessary grub entries, please refer to my thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643839/how-to-remove-unnecessary-efi-entries-from-grub).

Hope this helps?